# Amplifier power draw

Tags: batteries, amplifier, class-d

I'm working on a project where I'm going to drive 2 x 8-ohm loudspeakers using 1 (or more) car batteries and a Class-D amplifier. The setup is going to be used at a festival, so I need maximum efficiency from my system.

My question is, how does the amplifier draw power? Does it keep a constant load on the battery or does it vary according to the power needed from the loudspeakers? If I simply hook the amplifier up and simply vary the amplitude of the audio-signal, will it use power accordingly, or?

I'm considering this amplifier at the moment:
http://classdaudio.com/products/600w-class-d-power-amplifier.html since I should be able to drive it with 2-batteries in serial. Anything I should notice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 100% efficiency, the power drawn from the battery will be exactly the same as the power output to the speaker.

Real amplifiers are never 100% efficient, but a class D amplifier can be pretty efficient.  TI claims > 88% for the chip used in the amplifier you are looking at.

You should really look at the [tas5630 datasheet](http://focus.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=tas5630&fileType=pdf).

Here is power wasted vs. power output.  It is nearly a straight line.  Notice a few watts are drawn all the time, even with zero output:

[image]

Another graph to study carefully is this one.  Maybe two car batteries in series (for 24V) is not enough voltage to get your desired power output:

[image]

Comment: The labels of your first graph disagree with your description of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to worry about is peak current draw.
Car type batteries should be pretty good for this application, because they are rated to start a car, which needs a lot of current.
Just make sure you have some nice fat wires between the battery and the amplifier.
Also try not to discharge your car batteries all the way, it reduces their lifespan.